# How to convert javascript keycode to proper keycode?

Tags: c#, javascript, keycode

Is there a way I can convert a javascript keycode into one that is used by C#?

For example 87 is the character 'w' in javascript, but in C# it's 57. And 77 is 'm' whereas it's 4D in C#. Is there a simple way to convert them? Thanks.

Comment: But shouldn't "w" be 199 = 0x77 = 0167? "W" is 87 = 0x57 = 0127.

Comment: @D.Shawley: Key codes don't distinguish between upper- and lower-case letters. There's a `shiftKey`/`Shift` property for that.

Comment: Ah, yeah sorry. Was looking at this list http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/blvkc.htm and it didn't have the lower 'w' so didn't take much notice.

Comment: @minitech - character codes in JavaScript definitely do not discard case - "w".charCodeAt(0) is 199 and "W".charCodeAt(0) is 87.  It sounds like they do in C# though.  Learn something new every day.

Comment: @D.Shawley: I'm talking about the `keydown` event - key codes, not character codes. C# works the same way; otherwise, there would be some ASCII problems! :) [Here's an example jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/DvGTg/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue isn't that they're different; your C# ones are just in hexadecimal.

87<sub>10</sub> = 57<sub>16</sub>
77<sub>10</sub> = 4D<sub>16</sub>

Just treat them as `int`s, not as strings, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks! Never knew that. And yeah, it works as ints intead of strings. Thanks again.